# Convert complexe TSQL procedure to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have to move my DB from TSQL to PostgreSQL, I'm quite new with postgres and I don't found how I can convert this stored procedure to a function in postgres

This is my TSQL Stored Procedure (I simplify as much as I can)

Expected return list of Rows with 2 columns type (decimal,varchar)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.procSelectOpenDocument(
@ItemType_id decimal(38)
)
AS
IF @ItemType_id = 1
BEGIN
 SELECT d.ID, d.OrderNumber
 FROM dbo.Table1 d
END

IF @ItemType_id = 2
BEGIN
 SELECT d.ID, d.OrderNumber2
 FROM dbo.Table2 d
END
```

My problem?

if you Execute this in TSQL

```
execute dbo.procSelectOpenDocument(1)
```

Result

```
ID | OrderNumber
1  | Some String value

execute dbo.procSelectOpenDocument(2)
```

Result

```
ID | OrderNumber2
1  | Some String value
```

As to you can see, the list of Column name change depending of the parameter.

**But this is not working !!!!**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.procSelectOpenDocument(IN p_ItemType_id bigint)
 RETURNS TABLE
(
   ID bigint
  ,Name varchar(150)
)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' 
AS $function$ 
begin

 if p_ItemType_id = 1 then

     RETURN QUERY SELECT d.ID, d.OrderNumber    FROM dbo.Table1 d;


  end if;


  if p_ItemType_id = 2 then
       RETURN QUERY SELECT d.ID, d.OrderNumber2 FROM dbo.Table2 d;
  end if;

  end
  $function$;
```

Comment: And you want dont want the column names to change?

Comment: This is not (easily) possible in Postgres. The number and names of all columns must be known when parsing a SQL statement.

Comment: Yes I want column Name change ?

Comment: If is not possible in postgres what is the alternative solution ?

Answer (score 0):

with you dont alias the column name for the second query?

```
IF @ItemType_id = 2    
    BEGIN
     SELECT d.ID, d.OrderNumber2 as OrderNumber
     FROM dbo.Table2 d
    END
```

*EDIT after comments*

```
IF @ItemType_id = 1
BEGIN
 SELECT d.ID, d.OrderNumber, null as OrderNumber2
 FROM dbo.Table1 d
END

IF @ItemType_id = 2
BEGIN
 SELECT d.ID, null as OrderNumber, d.OrderNumber2
 FROM dbo.Table2 d
END
```

Comment: Has I say I simplify the sample but the goal is not to put alias if this was possible I know how to do it Thank for your help.

Comment: Can you post your postgresql so I can test it? Maybe prepare a minimal code in http://rextester.com ?  So you want different name depending on the parameter?

Comment: In the backend I use DataSet (.Net) and I way for a specific column name

Comment: I see now. In TSQL you get two different name. But in postgresql you get the same name?  .... I was confused because when you say  "The Problem" I tought that beheviour was the wrong one ... but looks like that is your desire behaviour?

Comment: Check my edit. Dont know if that work for you, but I would make my function return both fields so you always have the available fieldname, and choose which one to use in my client side.

Comment: Dont post in comment just edit your question, so other know what have you tryed]